# Proof that the set of doubly-stochastic matrices forms a convex polytope?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, birkhoff-polytopes

Does the set of all doubly-stochastic matrices form a convex polytope?  In general, I wonder how the proofs of convexity and geometry can be established for sets of matrices of this kind? Anything to do with the birkhoff's theorem!? Am not sure, if I am thinking in the right direction and hence the post.

Comment: I'm confused. Dense in what? It seems that the permutation matrices are contained in $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ which isn't dense in anything (it's discrete?)!

Comment: There are only finitely many permutation matrices (and generally more than one).  You might be confusing this with permutation matrices being in convex *position*.  But this is trivial to prove once you write down the definition.

Comment: Ok...well you are right, as any doubly-stochastic matrix can be written as a convex combination of permutation matrices (finite number). Do all the doubly stochastic matrices form a convex set? I wonder , if there is a well known strategy/theorem that proves/disproves these sets of matrices as forming convex polytopes?

Comment: @ErickWong That is an interesting case, though i did not mean 'convex position' while i posed the question (faulty question). I   also edited and changed permutation to doubly-stochastic, to stick to my initial direction of thought.

Comment: @qlinck The definition of a [convex set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) is very easy to verify for doubly-stochastic matrices, no strategy required.  Should your real question be how to prove that a given convex set is a [polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope)?

Comment: @ yes- a convex polytope, was my question. But as you said, it can be verified for being  a convex set individually. How about furthering this to see if it forms a polytope (geometrically)? Thanks.

Comment: Are you identifying $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ for the purposes of determining whether your set of interest is a convex polytope? If so, think about the natural constraints on a doubly stochastic matrix and formulate it as an intersection of half-spaces with respect to the "coordinates" $(a_{ij}) = A$.

Comment: Yes-if I vectorize the matrix and have the sum to one constraints. What do the constraints mean geometrically for this $n^2 \times 1$ dimensional vector- if the matrix was doubly-stochastic or even for that matter say, either of: row or column stochastic only? Can you clarify or put a reference/pointer to the statement 'intersection of half-spaces w.r.t the coordinates'?

Comment: I guess you meant each coordinate would be every vectorized matrix?

Comment: Let $\mathbf a = \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf A)$ where the vectorization stacks columns from left to right. Then, $0 \leq a_{ij} \leq 1$ must be satisfied and there are two matrices, $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf R$ in $\mathbb R^{n \times n^2}$ such that $\mathbf C \mathbf a = \mathbf 1$ and $\mathbf R \mathbf a = \mathbf 1$. This is already enough since there is, then, a matrix $\mathbf B$ and vector $\mathbf c$ such that $\mathbf A$ is doubly stochastic iff $\mathbf B \mathbf a \leq \mathbf c$ where the inequality is interpreted coordinatewise.

Comment: Wow..that's so interesting. I had never thought in these terms ever. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I only write this answer to summarize the comments.

We identify the space of matrix $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.
A matrix $(a_{i,j})_{i,j\leq n}$ is doubly stochastic if

1. $0\leq a_{i,j}\leq 1\ \forall i,j$
2. $\sum_i a_{i,j}=1 \ \forall j$
3. $\sum_j a_{i,j}=1 \ \forall i$

It is direct to check that if  $(a_{i,j})_{i,j\leq n}$ and $(b_{i,j})_{i,j\leq n}$ are doubly stochastic then $(t a_{i,j}+ (1-t) b_{i,j})_{i,j\leq n}$ is doubly stochastic for any $0\leq t\leq1$ (the conditions above are clearly fulfilled). This gives the convexity.

To observe that the set of doubly stochastic matrices is a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ we just need to have in mind that a polytope can be defined as a finite intersection of half-spaces.
The conditions above are actually $2n^2+4$ inequalities (have in mind that $a=b\iff (a\leq b \text{ and } b\leq a)$ ).

I think it is usual to consider that a polytope is bounded, here this is clear because of condition $1$.

**Edit:** As you suggested in your question, this is a direct corollary of [Birkhoff-Von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff.E2.80.93von_Neumann_theorem) theorem which is much stronger. The Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem states that the set of doubly stochastic matrices is the convex hull of the set of permutation matrices. Their is a finite number of permutations and the convex hull of a finite number of points is a convex body, so the corollary is immediate. 
But if you just want to see that this is a convex polytope without beeing more precise you don't need to use this theorem, the elementary arguments used above are sufficients.