# Find vertex of polyhedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, measure-theory, markov-chains, polyhedra

**Problem :** Show that the set of stationary measures for a [transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) forms a polyhedron with one vertex for each essential communicating class. (source : [1])

My trouble in 1 sentence : couldn't find vertex of polyhedron .

---

**Glossary :**

**stationary measure :** A stationary measure of a transition matrix $P$ is any [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) $\mu$ such that $\mu P=\mu $ .

**polyhedron :** A [polyhedron](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture2.pdf) $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as the solution set of a finite number of linear equalities and inequalities , and thus the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces and hyperplane , or compactly $S=\{x : Ax \preceq b , Cx = d\}$ with $A ,C\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}) ; x , b , d \in \mathbb{R}^n $ . A [vertex of polyhedron](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Ejvondrak/CS369P/lec3.pdf)  can form a supporting hyperplane to $S$ which only intersects $S$ at that vertex .

**essential communicating class :** For $x,y$ in state space , we denote $x \to y$ iff $(\exists r > 0)(P^r(x,y)> 0 )$ where $P^r(x,y)$ is the $r-$step transition probability from state $x$ to $y$ . We denote $x \leftrightarrow y$ iff $x\to y $ and $y \to x$ . The [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) under $\leftrightarrow$ are called communicating classes . A state $x$ is essential iff for all $y$ such that $x\to y$ , we have $y\to x$ . An essential communicating class contains at least $1$ essential state .

---

**Attempt :**

Suppose state space is $\mathcal{X}$ and $|\mathcal{X}| = n < \infty $ . Suppose there're $m$ essential communicating classes $C_i , i=1,...,m$ .
Let $A := \mathcal{X} \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^m C_i$  . Let $P$ be in the form
$
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{AA} & P_{AC_1} & ... & P_{AC_m} \\
\mathbf{0} & P_{\vert C_1} & ... & \mathbf{0} \\
: & \ddots & \ddots & :\\
\mathbf{0}  &  \mathbf{0} & ... &  P_{\vert C_m} 
\end{bmatrix}
$
(use elementary row operation if needed)
where $P_{AC_i}$ describes the transition from states in $A$ to states in $C_i$ , the [restricted matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2532488) $P_{\vert C_i}$ is stochastic , irreducible and by [5] recurrent .

The set of stationary measures of $P$ is $S = \{s^T : s \in S' \}$ where
$S' = \{ s : s \succeq \mathbf{0} , (P^T-I)s = \mathbf{0} \}$ forms a polyhedron in
$\mathbb{R}^n$ .

Then any stationary measure $s^T$ of $P$ will be in the form
$s^T = ( \mathbf{0} , o_1\gamma^{k\in C_1} , ... , o_m\gamma^{k\in C_m} )$ where $o_i \in (0,\infty) $ are constants and $\gamma^k$ as defined in [2] .

> To see this , let $s^T$ be any stationary measure of $P$ . By [3] , $s^T(A) = \mathbf{0}$ . By definition ,
> $$
> s^T(x \in C_i) = \sum_{y \in \mathcal{X}} s^T(y) P(y,x) 
> = \sum_{y \in C_i } s^T(y) P(y,x)  
> = \sum_{y \in C_i } s^T(y)  P_{|C_i}(y,x) 
> $$
> so the row vector $s^T(C_i) = (s^T(x) :  x\in C_i) $ is stationary measure to $P_{|C_i}$ , but [4] states that $s^T(C_i) = o_i \gamma^{k \in C_i} $ for some constant $o_i \in (0,\infty) $ such that $o_i^{-1}$ normalizes $s^T(k) $ .

But I couldn't specify a hyerplane and an element of $S'$ for each $C_i$ that satisfies the vertex definition above .

---

**References :**

[1] David and Yuval . Markov Chains & Mixing Times , p. 18 , exercise 1.14 .

[2] J.R. Norris . Markov Chains , theorem 1.7.5 .

> For Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with state space $I$ and a fixed state $k$ ,  consider for each $i$ the expected time spent in $i$ between visits to $k$ :
> $$
> \gamma_i^k = \mathbb{E}_k \sum_{n=0}^{T_k-1} 1_{\{X_n = i\}}
> $$
> Here the sum of indicator functions serves to count the number of times $n$ at which $X_n =i$ before the first passage time $T_k := \inf\{ n\ge 1 : X_n = k\}$ . 
>  
> If in addition , $P$ is irreducible and recurrent . Then 
> (i) $\gamma_{k}^k = 1$ 
> (ii) $\gamma^k = (\gamma_i^k : i \in I) $ satisfy $\gamma^k P = \gamma ;$ 
> (iii) $0 < \gamma_i^k < \infty $ for all $i \in I$

remark : In  Markov Chains & Mixing Times by David and Yuval, p. 11 , $\gamma^k_i = \tilde{\pi}(i) $ with $z = k $  .

[3] David and Yuval . Markov Chains & Mixing Times , p. 16 , proposition 1.28 .

> If $\pi$ is stationary for the finite transition matrix $P$ , then $\pi(y_0) = 0$ for all inessential states $y_0$ .

[4] J.R. Norris . Markov Chains , p.36 , Theorem 1.7.6 .

> Let $P$ be irreducible and let $\lambda$ be an invariant measure for $P$ with $\lambda_k =1 $ . Then $\lambda \ge \gamma^k$ . If in addition $P$ is recurrent , then $\lambda = \gamma^k$

[5] David and Yuval . Markov Chains & Mixing Times , p. 15 , remark 1.24 .

> For finite chains , a state $x$ is essential iff it's recurrent .

Comment: About the vertices, consider the polyhedron as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron), with vertices (1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), etc. for the case $n=4$. The general framework is the Birkhoff-Von Neumann theorem
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326040/305862.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't know how it could be applied here , because polyhedron here is formed by set of measures and I'm trying to find vertex by finding a supporting hyperplane that only intersects the polyhedron at a point . So I'd like more advice on the method to find vertex . But thanks for your information !

Comment: Your transition matrices are nothing else than stochastic matrices which are, according to the Birkhoff-von Neumann theorem I cited, in the convex hull of the extremal measures that given by permutation matrices.

Comment: @JeanMarie Are there any misunderstanding ? A possible one is that in my question the polyhedron is formed by the set of **stationary measures** defined in glossary , not transition matrices . If no misunderstanding  , then I have no idea how to use your theorem here , because first It's not obvious that the transition matrices here need to be doubly-stochastic . Second, for $n\times n$ transition matrices , stationary measures are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , the polyhedron of the set of stationary measures will be in a different space than the polyhedron of the set of transition matrices .

Comment: I must confess that, having taken a closer look to your text, I realize that it is much broader than the interpretation I had done at first of it.